# Gorenstein symmetric conjecture for arbitrary rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

The Gorenstein symmetric conjecture states that for Artin algebras $A$ one has the the regular module has finite injective dimension as a right module if and only if it has finite injective dimension as a left module. Let $id(M)$ denote the injective dimension of a module $M$.

> Question: Is there a general (noetherian if possible) ring $R$ with $id(R_R) \neq id(_{R}R)$?

I would expect that there is an easy counterexample or that this question has been considered before somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

By Lemma A of

*Zaks, Abraham*, [**Injective dimension of semi-primary rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(69)90007-6), J. Algebra 13, 73-86 (1969). [ZBL0216.07001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0216.07001),

if $R$ is Noetherian and $\text{id}(R_R)$ and $\text{id}(_RR)$ are both finite, then they are equal.

In

*Kirkman, E.; Kuzmanovich, J.; Small, L.*, [**Finitistic dimensions of Noetherian rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(92)90210-D), J. Algebra 147, No. 2, 350-364 (1992). [ZBL0765.16004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0765.16004).

the authors comment that they know of no example of a Noetherian ring with finite injective dimension on one side and infinite injective dimension on the other side, so there's probably no easy counterexample.

For non-Noetherian rings, there are well known examples of rings that are self-injective on one side but not on the other: for example, the ring of endomorphisms of a countable-dimensional vector space.